# Notepad++ Open file, change encoding and save from command line

Tags: command-line, character-encoding, notepad++

I search a way to do an automated task with Notepad++ from command line:

1. Open file
2. Change encoding to UTF-8
3. Save file

Is there any way to do it with some plugin or even with other program ?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use Notepad++ for that task? Which OS are you using?
Notepad++ got a Plugin-manager where you can install the Python Script plugin.

http://pw999.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/mass-convert-a-project-to-utf-8-using-notepad/

But if you want to convert files to UTF8 you can do that way easier with PowerShell on Windows or command line on Linux.

For Windows Power-Shell:

```
$yourfile = "C:\path\to\your\file.txt"
get-content -path $yourfile | out-file $yourfile -encoding utf8
```

For Linux use (e.g.) iconv:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 source.txt > new-file.txt
```

Comment: Powershell is OK as long as you want to your UTF8 files to contain a BOM, this is the default and not easily worked around.

Comment: @Broco the output file is empty when I run this script. Any idea why?

Comment: @Josh I think I find out why and a solution. Check my answer (if you still care about this)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Powershell script to change all the files in the current folder (and in all subfolders):

```
foreach ($file in @(Get-ChildItem *.* -File -Recurse)) {
    $content = get-content $file
    out-file -filepath $file -inputobject $content -encoding utf8
}
```

If you want to change only specific files just change the `*.*` (in the first line).

---

Note: I tried the pipe (`|`) approach in [Broco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24481910/146513) and was not working (I got empty output files [as Josh commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481776/notepad-open-file-change-encoding-and-save-from-command-line/69080351#comment94312082_24481910)). I think is because we probably cannot read and write directly from and to the same file (while in my approach I put the content into a memory variable).